# Why \pgfmathheight doesn't give the write height value

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, height

I want to know the height of a tikz node before drawing it, so I found a pgf command name \pgfmathheight who can give me the height of a char in pt. But actually when I try it with certain character like "y" the height doesn't seem to be right. I use this code to test it:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mylenHght{height("y")};
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mylenWdht{width("y")};
  \node[draw=blue,inner sep=0] (TestHeightNode) at (0,0) {y};
    \draw[draw=red] let %
    \p1 = (TestHeightNode.south west)%
    in (\x1,\y1) rectangle (\x1+\mylenWdht pt,\y1+\mylenHght pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: height is the part above the baseline, you want height + depth.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you you solve my problem

Comment: By the way, you can just do `\draw[red] (TestHeightNode.south west) rectangle +(\mylenWdth pt, \mylenHght pt);`.

Comment: Actually, it would be better if you could post the answer to your question as a proper answer and accept it. This way, it will be stored by the system. Otherwise, this question (although being solved) will pop up every now and then in the list of active questions, because it does not have a proper (and accepted) answer yet.

Comment: @JasperHabicht ok thank you I just answer the question but I can't actually accept it yet, I need to wait two days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So with all your suggestion the code look like this now:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mylenHght{height("y")+depth("y")};
  \pgfmathsetmacro\mylenWdht{width("y")};
  \node[draw=blue,inner sep=0] (TestHeightNode) at (0,0) {y};
  \draw[red] (TestHeightNode.south west) rectangle +(\mylenWdht pt,\mylenHght pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: the new result]

And my problem is solved, thank you all

Comment: If you're wondering why the red doesn't overlap the black rectangle. That's because of `outer sep = .5\pgflinewidth` placing the anchors on the outside of the line. Setting them to zero will make the lines overlap. (Or you adjust the corners of the rectangle manually by that amount in each direction.)